# Deciding number of parameter to pass to a method "dynamically"

Tags: scala, methods, parameters

In a call to a method I want to pass a parameter only if it exists. Below my call to the method:

```
    val bindingFuture =
    Http().bindAndHandle(
      endPoints,
      host,
      port,
      if (myParameter.isDefined) myParameter.get else //nothing
    )
```

My problem is that if parameter doesn't exist I want to pass to the method only three argument, ignoring the fourth. I would like to do this evaluation inside the calling to method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives:

You can **pattern match** on the option before calling the method to decide which of the two versions to call.

```
myParameter match {
  case Some(param) =>
    val bindingFuture =
      Http().bindAndHandle(
        endPoints,
        host,
        port,
        param
      )

  case None =>
    val bindingFuture =
      Http().bindAndHandle(
        endPoints,
        host,
        port
      )
}
```

Another option would be to see if the method supports a `null` *(highly possible if this is a **Java** lib)* so you can do this:

```
val bindingFuture =
  Http().bindAndHandle(
    endPoints,
    host,
    port,
    myParameter.orNull
  )
```

Finally, I would make my own wrapper which accepts options to hide the boilerplate.